# Powershell - Get-WmiObject filter

Tags: powershell

I need to get local admins on remote machine but need to show only domain users (Users with domain\prefix)

```
   $admins = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer computer   
    $admins = $admins |? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'} 
    $admins |% {  
    $_.partcomponent –match “.+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$” > $nul  
    $matches[1].trim('"') + “\” + $matches[2].trim('"') 
    } 

$admins = $admins |? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'}

GroupComponent   : \\COMPUTER\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="COMPUTER",Name="Administrators"
PartComponent    : \\COMPUTER\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="DOMAIN",Name="Domain Admins"
PSComputerName   : COMPUTER
```

**Current Output:**

COMPUTER\Administrator

DOMAIN\Domain Admins

DOMAIN\User1

DOMAIN\user2

I need to show only domain users

**Desired Output:**

DOMAIN\Domain Admins

DOMAIN\User1

DOMAIN\user2

I tried this:

```
$admins |% {  
$_.partcomponent –match “.+Domain\='DOMAIN\',Name\=(.+)$” > $nul  
$matches[1].trim('"') + “\” + $matches[2].trim('"') 
}
```

But single user is shown multiple times

DOMAIN\User1

DOMAIN\User1

DOMAIN\user1

Comment: You should make the output conditional on the `-match` operator: `if($_.PartComponent -match '...'){ $matches... }else{ Write-Warning "Couldn't extract name from $($_.PartComponent)"}`

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using `Get-LocalGroupMember` ?

Comment: Need to search multiple machines at once

Comment: As aside, don't use those curly so-called 'smart-quotes' `“` and `”` in code. Instead use straight ones `"`

Comment: it happened during copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out

```
$admins |% {  
$_.partcomponent –match ".+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$" > $nul 
$matches[1].trim('"') + "\" + $matches[2].trim('"') | Where-Object {$_ -like 'DOMAIN*' }
}
```

Output:

```
DOMAIN\Domain Admins
DOMAIN\user1
DOMAIN\User2
```

Comment: BTW: If you look closely on my answer, you would see that you can apply a small change to your regex and you don't need to trim anything.

Answer (score 1):

Please, please, please do not use that spaghetti code from TechNet gallery.

A good script is a well written (English) prose.

```bsh
Get-WmiObject Win32_GroupUser –Computer PlaceYourComputerNameHere | <# Now, you have all users #>
Where-Object {$_.GroupComponent –like '*"Administrators"'} | <# Now, you have all Administrators #>
Where-Object { $_.PartComponent  –match ".+Domain\=""(.+)"",Name\=(.+)$"} | <# Now, you have all domain administrators and you have created two regex groups by (.+) with index 1 and 2 #>
ForEach-Object {"$($Matches[1])\$($Matches[2])"} <# Now, you concatenated the results from regex matches into a single string #>
```

Comment: Thanks for tips but it's not answer for my question